# Is Playa as slow as built in Relationships with 1000s of entries?

Tags: playa, relationships, performance

I'm trying to relate multiple entries in a database with about 2,500 total entries in one channel. It takes a minute to load the full list in the control panel for each entry -- which is unacceptable for doing many of these each day. I know I can limit the entries, but I need to relate to previous entries throughout my database.

What I'm wondering is if Playa is any better at this? For those of you using it to relate to at least 2,000 entires in a channel, do you have to wait 60 seconds+ for the list to load? (And yes, I'm on a very fast Internet connection -- this appears to be a browser/server issue.) If it's much faster, I'll buy it ASAP!

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean that a single entry could have a single entry relating itself to over 2,000 other entries, or just that there are 2,000+ other entries to choose from?

If the latter, the answer is Yes, Playa is quite capable of dealing with large numbers of entries. Simply set a Limit on the Playa field to something like 100 entries, and then use the Search bar to get at whatever isn't immediately visible.

Comment: sorry for the delay in my response. Yes, it's the latter. I want to select up to a half-dozen from over 2,000 choices. Just to confirm, if I limit Playa to 100 entires and my required entry is not in that group will the search bar include ALL entries in the search (not just the 100)? EE's relationships does not do this. It only seems to search within the limited group.

Comment: Correct – the search goes over Ajax and searches across all possible entries.

Answer (score 1):

What version of ee are you using?

If it is below 2.6 you will see two additional columns in the exp_relationships table. These are rel_data and reverse_rel_data columns.

If these columns exist, thats your problem. In other words, these columns cache the content of the related entry.

Solution, upgrade ee as the new relationships field type looks to have been redesigned like playa, and i suggest it is much more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am using 2.6.1 and the two columns you mention are not in my db. However the problem is still there. Limiting the field to anything more than 1,000 entires is too slow to be useful. 500 max seems best.